# Powershell function with Parameters throwing null exception

Tags: powershell-2.0

This script is throwing a null exception and I am not certain why that is the case...

```
Function StopServices{    
    Param
    (
        $ServiceName,     
        $Remoteserver
    )
    write-host($Remoteserver)
    write-host($ServiceName)
    [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]$service = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $Remoteserver
}
```

the write-host writes the variable.  The Get-Service -ComputerName method throws this exception:

```
powershell cannot validate argument on parameter 'computername' the argument is null or empty
```

I am wondering what they are talking about,  Neither is empty...

```
StopServices("DUMMY","VALUES")
```

Neither of those are empty.  Why is it throwing that exception?

Answer (score 0):

I can run it like this:

> Function StopServices{
>       Param
>       (
>
> ```
>     $ServiceName,     
>     $Remoteserver
> )
> write-host($ServiceName)
> write-host($Remoteserver)
> Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $Remoteserver }
> ```
>
> StopServices $servicename $remoteserver

This will write the value of the vaiables and then run the get-service on it.